# Convert an array of objects to a hash based on a property of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

### Convert a JSON Array into a map based on key of the JSON object in the array

I'm trying to convert a JSON array into a map based on the property of the JSON element in the array.

Here is the structure of the JSON array:

```
[
{"property1": "x","property2": "value1","property3": "value1"},
{"property1": "x","property2": "value2","property3": "value2"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}
]
```

I want to split the JSON array into a map like this:

```
{
"x": [{"property2": "value1","property3": "value1"}, 
       {"property2": "value2","property3": "value2"}],

"y": [{"property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},
      {"property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}]
}
```

How can I do this with Javascript?

(P.S: I'm completely new to Javascript)

Comment: There's no such thing as a _JSON Array_. JSON is always a String.

Comment: And the word "map" is confusing, since JavaScript has `Map` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for maps, so you could do this:

```js
const data = [{"property1": "x","property2": "value1","property3": "value1"},{"property1": "x","property2": "value2","property3": "value2"},{"property1": "y","property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},{"property1": "y","property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}];

const map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.property1, []]));
data.forEach(({property1, ...rest}) => map.get(property1).push(rest));
const result = Object.fromEntries(map);

console.log(result);
```

The last assignment converts the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to a plain object in case you don't like working with Maps.

### ES5

`Map`, arrow functions, object literal spread syntax, ...etc are not available in ES5. In that version of JavaScript you would do this:

```js
const data = [{"property1": "x","property2": "value1","property3": "value1"},{"property1": "x","property2": "value2","property3": "value2"},{"property1": "y","property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},{"property1": "y","property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}];

var map = {}
data.forEach(function (o) {
    var cpy = Object.assign({}, o);
    delete cpy.property1;
    map[o.property1] = (map[o.property1] || []).concat(cpy);
});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: This is working good here, but Typescript/ES6/Babel is not supported in our internal AngularJS. How can we do without using '=>' and using plain Angularjs.

Comment: Ah, that restriction on the JavaScript version (ES5) should be mentioned in your question, and added as a tag. I have added an ES5 version to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```js
let a = [{
    "property1": "x",
    "property2": "value1",
    "property3": "value1"
  },
  {
    "property1": "x",
    "property2": "value2",
    "property3": "value2"
  },
  {
    "property1": "y",
    "property2": "value3",
    "property3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "property1": "y",
    "property2": "value4",
    "property3": "value4"
  }
];
let b = {};
for (o of a) {
  b[o.property1] = b[o.property1] || [];
  b[o.property1].push({
    property2: o.property2,
    property3: o.property3
  });
}
console.log(b);
```

What this code does is first creates a an `array` property for each `property1` if it doesn't already exist. Then it pushes a new object in that array with only the `property2` and `property3`.

Answer (score 0):

For a functional approach you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
var o = [
{"property1": "x","property2": "value1","property3": "value1"},
{"property1": "x","property2": "value2","property3": "value2"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}
]

var r = Object.values(o).reduce((ac, x) => ({
    ...ac,
    [x.property1]: [
       ...(ac[x.property1] || []),
       x
    ]
}), {})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Op needs the property1 to be omitted inside the individual objects.

Comment: I deliberitly copied over the entire object because this leads to clearer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and then decide if you want to start with an object literal or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

With Map:

```js
let data = [{ "property1": "x", "property2": "value1", "property3": "value1" }, { "property1": "x", "property2": "value2", "property3": "value2" }, { "property1": "y", "property2": "value3", "property3": "value3" }, { "property1": "y", "property2": "value4", "property3": "value4" } ]

let result = data.reduce((r,{property1, property2, property3}) => 
  r.set(property1, { property2, property3 }), new Map())

console.log(Object.fromEntries(result))
```

With object literal as the accumulator:

```js
let data = [{ "property1": "x", "property2": "value1", "property3": "value1" }, { "property1": "x", "property2": "value2", "property3": "value2" }, { "property1": "y", "property2": "value3", "property3": "value3" }, { "property1": "y", "property2": "value4", "property3": "value4" } ]

let result = data.reduce((r,{property1, property2, property3}) => { 
  r[property1] = r[property1] || []
  r[property1].push({ property2, property3 })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my approach to solving this. I'm by no means an expert and I'm sure other users could provide a better solution. But until then you can see if this helps.

Essentially we want to filter out the two collections (x and y) using the .filter expression. Then for those collections, we'll remove the property we used to filter on. Then finally create a new object combining the remaining collections.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9bxg8wv/1/

```
const dataSource = [
{"property1": "x","property2": "value1","property3": "value1"},
{"property1": "x","property2": "value2","property3": "value2"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value3","property3": "value3"},
{"property1": "y","property2": "value4","property3": "value4"}
];

let xContainer = dataSource.filter(x => x.property1 === "x");
let yContainer = dataSource.filter(y => y.property1 === "y");

xContainer.forEach((e) => {
  delete e.property1;
});

yContainer.forEach((e) => {
  delete e.property1;
});

let mappedDataSource = {
    "x": xContainer,
    "y": yContainer
};

console.log(mappedDataSource);
```

Comment: @AmitDas Updated with an explanation